# Typescript Object destructuring results in "Property assignment expected."

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-2016, destructuring

I am transitioning a project from Babel to Typescript and receive the following compiler error:

```
error TS1136: Property assignment expected.
```

from code that looks like this:

```
var auth = {...this.props.auth};
```

This code previously worked fine under Babel, but causes the error above when attempting to compile via Typescript. Is object destructuring different in Typescript?

Comment: shouldn't it be `var { auth } = this.props;`?

Comment: Isn't this ES7 syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is [Object spread/rest operators](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) (proposed for ES7). It looks like it's planned but not yet implemented:

> We want to wait for the proposal to reach Stage 3 before addressing this.

More info [**here**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103).

**Edit**: The proposal is in stage-3. We'll likely see it drafted on ES2018 (ES9). [Support has been added to TypeScript as well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest)  (starting from 2.1).